# Java: Preview HttpPost Request

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to send JSON formatted data to a server using Java. The information is getting to the server, but the server is responding with a "Bad Request".

```
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(path);

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(JSONRequest);

    //sets the post request as the resulting string
    httpost.setEntity(se);

    //sets a request header so the page receving the request will know what to do with it
    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf8");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```

That is the basic setup of my request. Here is the JSONData:

```
    {"clientApplicationDto":{"AuthenticationToken":"","BrandId":12,"MobileDeviceApplicationId":0},"mobileDeviceInfo":{"CarrierName":"MTN-SA","OsVersion":"2.2.2","ClientApplicationVersion":"TEST","DeviceManufacturer":"HTC","DeviceName":"HTC Desire","DeviceUniqueId":"1e9766fa2ef4c53a","OsName":"8","ClientApplicationTypeId":3}}
```

If this looks right to you lot, I'll start spamming the admins, but for now, I need to know if I am missing something.

Comment: Hm.. for starters, `StringEntity` (or rather any `AbstractHttpEntity` subclass) has a content-type, it will by default be set to the constants `HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE`, using `HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET` as the character set. Consider setting your Content-type by calling `se#setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8")` instead. Your JSON looks well-formed btw.

Comment: Just to check if its a problem with the post or the java code have you tried the request in something like the Chrome REST console? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the issue... The server is extremely sensitive to the content type header and the content format

```
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf8");
```

Needed to be changed to

```
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

and 
         StringEntity se = new StringEntity(JSONRequest);

needed to be changed to

```
     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(JSONRequest,"utf-8");
```

Thanks Jens, that one comment pushed me into the right direction.

Comment: Nice to know it helped you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it's good for u

```
    private static String sendRequestPost(String url, Object obj) {
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
            if (obj != null) {
                httpost.setEntity(new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(obj), "utf-8"));
                System.out.println("Request Json => " + new Gson().toJson(obj));
            }
            httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf8");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpost);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            return strResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }

    }
```